# Fetching records corresponding to a user, when queried from admin role/user which has access to all records

Tags: parse-server

I need to fetch a particular class (say Class A) records corresponding to each user in my parse server, when queried with admin role which have access to all the records in that particular class (Class A).

How can I do that?

Quick help would be greatly appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want these records on the client, but the client doesn't have "permission" to get all class a records?

If I've got the problem right, then here's a solution.  Create a cloud code function that can use the master key to query objects of class a.

```
// this is the cloud function that you can call with
// whichever client SDK you are using....
const fetchClassA = function (request, response) {
  const result = [];
  const userId = request.params.fetchForUser;
  // the test here should be against role, just an example....
  if (request.user.get('username') !== 'admin') {
    response.error('you are not authorized.');
    return;
  }
  if (!userId) {
    response.error('no user supplied');
    return;
  }

  const user = new Parse.User();
  user.id = userId;

  new Parse.Query('ClassA')
    .equalTo('user', user)
    // depending on the use case, you may want to use 
    // find here instead?
    .each((object) => {
      result.push(object);
    }, { useMasterKey: true })
    .then(() => response.success(result))
    .catch(response.error);
}

// the rest of this is just a unit test to "lightly" test
// our cloud function....
describe('fetch record with a cloud function', () => {
  const userA = new Parse.User();
  const userB = new Parse.User();

  beforeEach((done) => {
    userA.setUsername('userA');
    userA.setPassword('abc');
    userB.setUsername('userB');
    userB.setPassword('def');
    Parse.Object.saveAll([userA, userB])
      .then(() => Parse.Object.saveAll([
        new Parse.Object('ClassA').set('user', userA),
        new Parse.Object('ClassA').set('user', userA),
        new Parse.Object('ClassA').set('user', userA),
        new Parse.Object('ClassA').set('user', userB),
        new Parse.Object('ClassA').set('user', userB),
        new Parse.Object('ClassA').set('user', userB),
      ]))
      .then(() => Parse.User.signUp('admin', 'foo'))
      .then(done)
      .catch(done.fail);
  });

  it('should fetch class a', (done) => {
    Parse.Cloud.define('fetchClassA', fetchClassA);
    Parse.Cloud.run('fetchClassA', { foo: 'bar', fetchForUser: userA.id })
      .then(result => expect(result.length).toBe(3))
      .then(done)
      .catch(done.fail);
  });
});
```